# Exercise in python is returning None

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a recursive function that receives a list and a target element and returns True if the element is in the list and False, otherwise.

EXAMPLES:

```
busca ([1,2,3], 2) -> returns True
busca ([], 49) -> returns False
```

I can't use Python's `"x in list"` command.

I've developed code, but it returns None for some cases. For others, it works correctly.

```
def busca(lista, alvo):
    if len(lista) == 0:
        return False

    if alvo == lista[0]:
        return True

    if len(lista) == 1:
        return False
    else:
        nova = lista[1:]
        busca(nova, alvo)


# busca([3, 2, 1], 3)
```

Comment: on the last line of function definition try to `return busca(nova, alvo)`

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `None` when it ends in the following condition:

```
else:
    nova = lista[1:]
    busca(nova, alvo)   # even when this execution return True/False it's not returned by calling function
```

Did you mean?

```
else:
    nova = lista[1:]
    return busca(nova, alvo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you return False when the length of the list is equal to 1. I mean

```
2 in [2]  => True
```

despite

```
len([2]) => 1
```

and:

```
busca([2], 2) => True
```

This makes more sense to me:

```
def busca(lst, tgt):

    if len(lst) !=0:
        if lst[0] == tgt:
            return True
        else:    
            return busca(lst[1:], tgt)
    else: 
        return False
```

Can you explain?